# jquery/javascript finding the value within a dynamically created element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated html table whose columns have id assigned dynamically. 
for ex:

```
   <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
     ....
     ....
   <td id="n">n</td>
```

in order to get the get value of a specific column I am using
        `document.getElementById("#myvar").innerHTML` or `$("td#myvar").html` where myvar is variable that contains search element such as   2 or 3 etc. But I dont get any results. If I direcly use a number for `document.getElementById("#2").innerHTML` , it works. Please advise what to do to get value where id of element is same as the variable declared??

Answer (score 5):

First, the `getElementById()` DOM method expects an ID, not a jQuery selector.

Second, neither JavaScript nor jQuery provide variable interpolation in strings, as you seem to be assuming. You have to build your own string:

```
var myvar = 2;
$("td#" + myvar).html()
```

Last but not least, remember that [the ID attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) cannot start with a digit unless you are using HTML 5.

Answer (score 3):

use this -

```
$("#"+myVar).html();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong. When using document.getElementById, you don't include the # sign. When using jQuery id selectors, you do use the # sign, but you need to call .html() as a function.

```
document.getElementById("myvar").innerHTML

$('#myvar').html();
```

If myvar is a variable, omit the quotes, for instance if `myvar = "2";` then your selectors would be:

```
document.getElementById(myvar).innerHTML
```

For jQuery, use string concatenation:

```
$('#' + myvar).html();
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` accepts a string argument which is the id of the element you'd like to select, so you won't need to include #, i.e.

```
document.getElementById(myvar).innerHTML
```

Should work

Not directly related to your question, but it is invalid for an ID attribute to start with a number

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").